# Argument dependent lookup for classes in top-level namespace?

Tags: c++, c++03, argument-dependent-lookup

I have a class that is in top-level namespace for historical reasons. I need to define a function for it that must<sup>1</sup> be found using argument-dependent lookup. Is the top-level namespace considered associated namespace of such class or do I have to make some workaround?

<sup>1</sup><sub>Otherwise the template that uses it might not find it, because symbols defined after the template are only seen when found by ADL.</sub>

Comment: Why do you need argument-dependent lookup for functions in the global namespace?

Comment: @ChrisDrew I believe that's explained in the footnote.

Comment: @Angew: I see. Is there a good reason why the function can't be declared before the template?

Comment: @ChrisDrew I'd say that because it would require header files to be included in a specific order, and that's something you simply **must** avoid in any projects of non-trivial size.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: It is independent type that needs to implement a concept. Trying to dictate order of inclusion would yield a complete mess.

Comment: @Angew OK, I see, the header containing the template can't include the header containing the declaration of the function because that function depends on the type. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global namespace is not special in this regard, it works just like any other namespace and is thus perfectly fine for your use case.

[**Live example 1**](http://ideone.com/7oZDdg) of global namespace working.

[**Live example 2**](http://ideone.com/n69opD) of ADL actually being the reason #1 works<sup>1</sup>.

Here's the text of the live example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {};

template <class T>
void bar(T t)
{
  foo(t);
}

void foo(X x)
{
  std::cout << "Foo\n";
}

int main()
{
  X x;
  bar(x);
}
```

<sup>1</sup> This fails, because ADL cannot find the function, while normal lookup would. So it proves that #1 really works thanks to ADL.

Comment: @Rapptz Which one? The second one is supposed to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on the standard:

From [basic.lookup.argdep] (2):

> — If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are:
>   the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and its
>   direct and indirect base classes. Its associated namespaces are the
>   innermost enclosing namespaces of its associated classes.

From [basic.namespace] (2) (and 3.3.6 where `global namespace` is defined):

> The outermost declarative region of a translation unit is a namespace; see 3.3.6.

So I don't see anything to exclude the global namespace from ADL.